# Question about mathematical logic ∀x ∈ S, ∀z ∈ S, ∃y ∈ C

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

∀x ∈ S, ∀z ∈ S, ∃y ∈ C,(x != z) ⇒ ¬(T(x, y) ∧ T(z, y))

I'm trying to express this in English, but I can't use the variables x or y in my sentence.

Basically it means for elements x in S, and all elements z in S, There exists a y in C, such that x being different than z implies.....

How can I say this without using the variables?  Cheers.

Comment: $\forall x$ means for all x...$\in$ means in... so for the first one it's for all x belonging in S.

Comment: I know that, but I can't use 'x' in my sentence.

Comment: strange...wait let me look something up for a bit.

Comment: I just read a section in my book and it does mention the variables in some example sentences. Who told you that you can't use them?

Comment: I know technically you 'can' use them, but for this specific question I can't.

Comment: Can you use *different* variables?

Answer (score 1):

"For any two different elements of the set $S$, there is an element of set $C$ which is not in the $T$ relation with both of them."

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Can you please explain how you concluded 'For any two different elements of the set S'? I'm just trying to create a general rule when dealing with these types of statements.

Comment: I interpreted the meaning of the formula. The word 'different' is coming from the condition $x\ne y$.